# VBA msgbox sheets delete userform option

Tags: excel, vba

I want to delete all sheets (Sheet1 to Sheet6) in my workbook. What I have made, is that I have used userform, and by the click on the button "delete data" I want to delete all data on the mentioned sheets. My code so far..

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Unload Me
Dim ws As Worksheets
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each ws In Worksheets
If MsgBox("This command will delete all data?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then UserForm1.Show Else ws.Delete
End If
Next ws
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

This one does not work. I am novice with VBA and this loop is too way complicated for me. Any ideas how could I do that? Thanks

Comment: "it does not work" means nothing, it's what users send to the support email and drives you nuts because you can't tell what their actual problem is. Please read [ask]. And your code wants to be indented.

Comment: You want to delete the sheets or delete the data in the sheets? And also if the user presses no in every sheet then you want to show the userform that many times?

Comment: if you only have sheets 1 through 6 then you cannot delete the last sheet.  The workbook needs at least 1 sheet.  If you just want to delete the data then clear the contents of the sheet ws.Cells.ClearContents.  Since you are new to VBA I would highly suggest you take some time and review some of the tutorials on the web about it as there is nothing really complicated about the loop.

Comment: I have not expressed myself good. I want to delete data in all sheets, not sheets themselves. I have one userform on sheet1, with the command on userform1 I want to delete all the data on sheet1 to sheet6. I have done the command for deleting all the data on sheet1, but I dont know how to do that on all sheets by one click, on userform1.

Comment: To delete the data, you can just do like `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.ClearData` or `.Delete` instead of `ClearData`. So, `ws.cells.delete` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just something like

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    ws.UsedRange.ClearContents
Next
```